# How to prevent accented characters from making a PHP regex fail?

Tags: php, regex

The below call to `preg_replace` fails and returns an empty string when `content` contains accented characters such as `à` or `ÿ`.

```
preg_replace('@([^=][^"])(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.\%\+#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>', $content);
```

I rewrote the regex in `preg_replace` this way, and it worked:

```
preg_replace('@([^=][^"])(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.\%\+#ÂÃÄÀÁÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>', $content);
```

How can I make it shorter?

Comment: i dont think so cause if i put only \w it block always when it see a accented character

Comment: @chris85: no! `\w` contains non-ascii characters when the u modifier is used or when the pattern starts with `(*UCP)`. And even when the u modifier or `(*UCP)` is used, it doesn't match letters with a combining mark.

Comment: where do i set the u ? after the closing of my regex delimiter ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh, `Â` is the combined character, didn't see that. How'd you spot that?

Comment: @Mireille28 I was thinking you were looking for a different version of the character, not the combined accent character.

Comment: @chris85: there are several versions, it can be a character already accented or an ascii character followed by a combining mark. For example: `â` *(one unicode point)* and `a^` *(two unicode points)* *(it's only a representation)*

Comment: someone have a example that will not block on any accented character even the Â with my first example i have put in the question im working on that for long time and still cant find a good solution unless i write all accented characters in the regular expression like my second example show

Comment: seem to work when i do this 

`preg_replace('@^(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.~\%\+#-=]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@ui', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);`

Answer (score 1):

Use unicode may solve your problem.

`[\u00bf-\u00ff]`